# jQuery Drop Down Menu Implementation

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I've tried implementing:
http://aext.net/2009/08/perfect-sign-in-dropdown-box-likes-twitter-with-jquery/

Which works perfectly, it shows when you click the link, then if you click it again it hides it. It also hides if you click anywhere else on the document whilst it's open.

I've tried implementing in to this page:
http://hevvo.eu/~dev/backtrack/index.php

However, it only works when you click on it, then click on the document, not if you click on the link again. I just can't figure out what's different about my code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added this which fixed it.

```
    $(".sign-in").mouseup(function() {
            return false
        });
```

Thanks to all those that helped.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that you aren't calling `preventDefault()` on the event object in the click handler. Also your trigger link has the class menu-open hard-coded to it.

### Edit

When binding an event handler in jQuery, the function is automatically passed an event object which has various properties and methods which you can make use of. One of these methods is called `preventDefault()` and stops the browser performing its default action when that event is fired. You can call this method like this:

```
$("a_selector").click(function(event) {

    //stop browser performing default action, e.g following a link
    event.preventDefault();

    //do your other stuff here
});
```

The event object is passed to the handler in any of jQuery's event-handling methods, such as `bind()`, `live()`, `delegate()` or `on()` (with `on()` being the preferred method of course, as `live()` and `delegate()` are now deprecated)

Comment: Sorry I hardcoded that in to test something. And what do you mean I'm not calling preventDefault()?

Comment: Yeah I looked in to that just now and I've added it, but alas, it still doesn't work, when there's literally nothing different about my code and his. Yet his works, this is really starting to irritate me.

Comment: I think I've found a way of fixing it, could you please check my code again? The only issue now is when a user is alternating between Login and Register, it doesn't work quite right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, when a user clicks login, then clicks off on to the document, it takes 2 clicks in order to show the form again.